# Create a tree using a stack

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

def createTree(vector):
    # Initialise a stack
    stack = []

    # Initialise a root
    root = Node(vector[0])
    for val in vector[1:]:
        root, stack = addNode(val, stack, root)
    return root

def addNode(x, stack, root):
    while len(stack) != 0 and stack[-1].value < x:
        stack.pop()
    
    node = Node(x)
    if len(stack) == 0:
        node.leftChild = root
        root = node
    else:
        if stack[-1].rightChild is None:
            node.leftChild = stack[-1].rightChild
        stack[-1].rightChild = node
    stack.append(node)
    return root, stack

root = createTree([1, 5, 8, 4, 3, 7, 6, 2])
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQIuG.png)

I am suppose to get this tree with that snippet, but I am not getting it. I am not getting the left child of the node 7. Is that normal? How can I fix that issue?

Comment: There's nothing in your code which produces any output, so please clarify how you are determining that the result is not correct. Also, your code here is going to raise an `AttributeError` because the `.valeur` attribute does not exist. Please see [mcve].

Comment: @kaya3, although an output is not presented in the code, it's fairly clear that `root` is supposed to hold the constructed tree (and it does, once the error in the logic is fixed)

Comment: @Grismar Yes, and how is OP determining that the tree is not correct? What are they doing to investigate it? You need more code to see the contents of the tree, and that code needs to be included in the question.

Comment: You don't in fact, if you scroll down, you'll see I had no trouble reading the code, spotting the error, fixing it and verifying the result with a debugger.

Comment: @Grismar With all due respect, the fact that you were able to write an answer does not negate the need for people to write a [mcve] when they ask a question. There are two very good reasons - it saves work for the people who answer questions, and it ensures that the issue is not caused by some code that the OP thought was irrelevant and didn't include (or, that there isn't *another* issue in the code they didn't include). If OP determined that the output is incorrect using a debugger, the question should include that information, as I said.

Comment: That would certainly have helped - I've provided such a method in my answer, in case someone would like to verify. I felt that the code was clear enough without a visualisation routine (which OP then probably would have to write themselves - not trivial), but I agree with you that it's not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `not` in this line:

```
if stack[-1].rightChild is None:
```

i.e.:

```
if stack[-1].rightChild is not None:
```

Your code works fine otherwise (except for the spelling error in `.valuer`, which would be `.value`)

In case someone wants to print the tree to validate (because that may be an issue):

```
def printTree(root):
    print(f'value: {root.value}, '
          f'on the left {root.leftChild.value if root.leftChild else None}, '
          f'on the right {root.rightChild.value if root.rightChild else None}')
    if root.leftChild:
        printTree(root.leftChild)
    if root.rightChild:
        printTree(root.rightChild)
```

Result:

```
value: 8, on the left 5, on the right 7
value: 5, on the left 1, on the right None
value: 1, on the left None, on the right None
value: 7, on the left 4, on the right 6
value: 4, on the left None, on the right 3
value: 3, on the left None, on the right None
value: 6, on the left None, on the right 2
value: 2, on the left None, on the right None
```

Comment: Perfect answer!!

Comment: If the answer works for you @Patrick, please click the check  mark next to it, so that the answer appears answered to others as well and they don't waste time on reading it (or don't find it if they have a similar problem)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the worst case complexity of `addNode()`? When does that happen?

Comment: I could compute it, but I think the point of the exercise is for you to try that yourself :) - if you run into problems computing it, you could consider posting a separate question about your computation

Comment: I don't want you to compute it. I am just interested when it happens.